# Changing UI values from another class

Tags: java, swing, encapsulation

I'm implementing Consumer-Producer problem in Java and I need to add guy to this. My problem is in changing UI components from `Customer` or `Producer` classes.

I don't know how I can call those components from other - not related class. When I've tried to get e.g `height` of component everything works like a charm but when I'm trying to `set` anything, nothing happens!

This is my `Producer` class code with some tries:

```
public class Producer extends Thread {
    // Variable which holds shared queue
    private BlockingQueue<String> queue;
    // Amount products created by producer
    private int steps;
    // Object with normaln distribution
    private NormalDistribution distribution;

    // Accessors to the frame
    private PCPMainFrame frame;
    private JSlider queueSlider;
    private JProgressBar queueProgressBar;

    // Constructor with 4 arguments
    // q                    - is our queue shared between customer and producer
    // steps                - amount of products
    // mean                 - parameter rquired for normal distribution
    // standardDeviation    - ditto
    public Producer(BlockingQueue<String> q, int steps, double mean, double standardDeviation){
        this.queue=q;
        this.steps = steps;
        this.distribution = new NormalDistribution(mean, standardDeviation);
        this.frame = new PCPMainFrame();
        this.queueSlider = frame.getQueueSlider();
        this.queueProgressBar = new JProgressBar();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Generating products and filling queue with them
        for(int i = 0; i < steps; i++){
            try {
                long sleepTime = Math.abs((long)distribution.sample()*100);
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                // Saving element in queue
                queue.put(String.valueOf(i));
                // This is a log for developer needs, feel free to uncomment
                System.out.println("Produced: " + i);
                queueSlider.setValue(steps);
                frame.setQueueProgressBar(queueProgressBar);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Producer exception: " + e);
            }
        }
        // Ading exit message at the end of the queue
        String exit = new String("exit");
        try {
            queue.put(exit);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Queue exception: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm there is nothing special about swing, just call your components just like you'd call any object of any normal class?

Comment: I know it should work that way, but as you can see in this code sample when I'm calling `queueSlider.setValue(steps);`nothing happens...

Comment: The value of steps never changes

Comment: This is my desperate step... I know it never changes but I can't do anything with Swing components from Producers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer after a lot of pain!

Here is what I have done:
I've added `JFrame` argument to my `Producer` constructor and when I'm constructing producer in `startButtonMouseClicked` I'm passing `this` as an argument of `JFrame` type. This litre trick has given me an access to everything just the way I want it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to modify what the GUI looks like outside of the Event Dispatch Thread, you have a few options. You can use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` and pass a `Runnable` that does your task, or use a `SwingWorker`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you actually display your frame.

Here is example code from the basic Swing tutorial:

JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

```
//Add the ubiquitous "Hello World" label.
JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
frame.getContentPane().add(label);

//Display the window.
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

EDIT:
Note that you are missing the bottom two lines. (If you can already see a frame, I am guessing that you are actually looking at a different frame, not the one that is generated in your code.)